# "Подхват" значения из input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не могу реализовать так, чтобы кнопка Купить брала значение из инпута, именно то которое прописано в поле, но когда смотрю код элемента, у этого инпута значение value=0, не изменяется. И получается что кнопка Купить берет всяких раз значение которое было прописано первоначально т.е. 0. Как возможно это исправить? Вот код:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // This button will increment the value
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      // Increment
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  });
  // This button will decrement the value till 0
  $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      // Decrement one
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  });
  $('.button__buy').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var quantity = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
  });
});
```

```css
#myform {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  margin: 2%;
}

.qty {
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

input.qtyplus {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

input.qtyminus {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.button__buy {
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #027603;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
  <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
  <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
  <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
  <input class="button__buy" type="button" value="Купить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверил, обработчик клика по кнопке берет актуальное значение

```js
$('.button__buy').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var quantity = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
});
```